# Apache ModSecurity: another rule with the same id error

Tags: apache, docker, mod-security

I am trying to set up an Apache server with the [ModSecurity Rule set](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs) inside a Docker container. I followed a few tutorials ([this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu), [this](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/04/09/how-to-configure-modsecurity-with-apache-on-ubuntu-linux/) and [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/configure-modsecurity-on-apache/)) to build a secure Apache server. But I am unable to make the server work with the rule set.

I get this error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 855 of /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf:
ModSecurity: Found another rule with the same id
```

I searched for the error and according to the answers [on this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/604746/mod-security-another-rule-with-same-id) the fault lies in including the same rules twice. But as far as I can see, I am not including the same rules twice and I wonder if the error lies elsewhere.

My project file structure is the following:

```
.
├── conf
│   └── httpd.conf
├── Dockerfile
├── index.html
├── modsecurity.d
│   ├── crs-setup.conf
│   ├── modsecurity.conf
│   └── rules
```

The `httpd.conf` file is the default config file used for an Apache server and the modsecurity configurations are inserted via commands in the Dockerfile.

The Dockerfile has the following configuration

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install less which tree httpd mod_security && \
    yum clean all

COPY index.html /var/www/html/

#COPY conf/ /etc/httpd/conf/
COPY modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/
COPY modsecurity.d/modsecurity.conf /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/
COPY modsecurity.d/rules/* /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/rules/

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "<IfModule security2_module>" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "  Include modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "  Include modsecurity.d/rules/*.conf" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "  SecRuleEngine On" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "</IfModule>" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

`index.html` is just a basic hello file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" lang="en">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello there</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`crs-setup.conf` has the following content (excluding all the comments)

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,pass"
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,auditlog,pass"
SecCollectionTimeout 600
SecAction \
 "id:900990,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:tx.crs_setup_version=310"
```

`modsecurity.conf` has only these two lines

```
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecStatusEngine On
```

`rules` is a directory which contains the ModSecurity rule set.

I also placed the project files on [github](https://github.com/gellati/owasp-modsecurity-apache) if anyone wants to have a look at the whole setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why I got the error. The ModSecurity configuration file was misnamed and the rule files had been placed in the wrong directory.

The ModSecurity file was `modsecurity.conf`, when in fact it should have been `mod_security.conf`, notice the underscore [(source)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html). The rule files should have been placed in a folder called `activated_rules`[(source)](https://www.modsecurity.org/CRS/Documentation/install.html).

In my working configuration I now have the following folder structure:

```
.
├── conf
│   └── httpd.conf
├── Dockerfile
├── index.html
└── modsecurity.d
    ├── crs-setup.conf
    ├── mod_security.conf
    └── activated_rules
```

The `Dockerfile` is as follows

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install less which tree httpd mod_security && \
    yum clean all

COPY index.html /var/www/html/

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "<IfModule security2_module>" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "Include modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "Include modsecurity.d/activated_rules/*.conf" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN echo "</IfModule>" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf


COPY modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf     /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/
COPY modsecurity.d/mod_security.conf  /etc/httpd/conf.d/
COPY modsecurity.d/rules/*            /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```